# SQL Service Broker weird issue with permission

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, service-broker

I am facing an issue using SQL service broker (in SQL Server 2012) and SqlDependency in C#. The situation is that the DB machines are initially deployed with the database and the security group which is used to access the DB is a member of db_owner role, later I deploy it with an update script that adds more tables, stored procedures and jobs and on the application server I roll out new build which has the changes to use SqlDependency to get notifications. When the application starts I get the following exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An entity of type service cannot be owned by a role, a group, or by principals mapped to certificates or asymmetric keys...Invalid object name 'SqlQueryNotificationService-36f1b73f-3477-4b10-ad67-985e1092afff'.....Server stack trace: ..   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()..   at SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.SqlConnectionContainer.CreateQueueAndService(Boolean restart)..   at SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.SqlConnectionContainer..ctor(SqlConnectionContainerHashHelper hashHelper, String appDomainKey, Boolean useDefaults)..   at SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.Start(String connectionString, String& server, DbConnectionPoolIdentity& identity, String& user, String& database, String& queueService, String appDomainKey, SqlDependencyPerAppDomainDispatcher dispatcher, Boolean& errorOccurred, Boolean& appDomainStart, Boolean useDefaults)..   at SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.StartWithDefault(String connectionString, String& server, DbConnectionPoolIdentity& identity, String& user, String& database, String& service, String appDomainKey, SqlDependencyPerAppDomainDispatcher dispatcher, Boolean& errorOccurred, Boolean& appDomainStart)..   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)..   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)....Exception rethrown at [0]: ..   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)..   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)..   at SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.StartWithDefault(String connectionString, String& server, DbConnectionPoolIdentity& identity, String& user, String& database, String& service, String appDomainKey, SqlDependencyPerAppDomainDispatcher dispatcher, Boolean& errorOccurred, Boolean& appDomainStart)..   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(String connectionString, String queue, Boolean useDefaults)..

But when I log on to the DB servers and remove the db_owner role for that security group and add it back (using SQL Management studio UI) everything seems to work, the exception at the application is gone and it can now create the service & queue at the SQL server (adding and removing role using sp_addrolemember and ALTER ROLE does not solve the issue only doing it through UI works). I’m not sure what is the root cause of the issue and i want to fix the problem than to go around it.

Comment: Does 'deploy' mean you are restoring a backup from one server to another? Sometimes, even though the user or group names seem to be the same, they have different SID's on each server, and after restoring from a backup from a different physical server, they need to be dropped and re-added.

Comment: By 'deploy' i mean that a .sql script was run on the server which created database and set up permissions for the user or do other actions. Every other thing is working fine, its just taht the SqlDependency does not work even though the security group is member of db_owner role and removing and adding the security group to that role solves the problem.